# Html.fromHtml() text formatting and multi dimensional arrays

Tags: android, arrays, string

The app that I am working on is very text heavy and has a couple expandable lists, so I'm using multi dimensional arrays to fill out the child views.
I want to bold certain parts of the text like this:
Example 1: This is an example.
So to do this, I have this in my strings.xml:

```
<string name="example"><![CDATA[<b>Example 1:</b> This is an example.]]></string>
```

Over to my adapter:

```
CharSequence example = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.example);
```

Imagine tons of those, and then I fit them into my array:

```
private CharSequence [][] childview = { 
   {example, example1, example2, example3};
   {example4, example5, example6, example7};
};
```

Question is, there's got to be a better way to do this than to create a whole bunch of variables right? Can I make my strings into a string array and fit them into the multi dimensional array with Html.fromHtml formatting?

Comment: that's more a [] than a [][]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a little utility method:

```
public CharSequence [][] fromRes(int[][] resIdMatrix) {
    CharSequence[][] result = new CharSequence[resIdMatrix.length][];
    int i = 0;
    for (int[] resIds : resIdMatrix) {
        CharSequence[] row = result[i++] = new CharSequence[resIds.length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int id : resIds) {
            row[j++] = Html.fromHtml(getString(id));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then call it with a two-dimensional array of resource IDs:

```
int[][] resIds = {
    {R.string.example, R.string.example1, R.string.example2, R.string.example3},
    {R.string.example4, R.string.example5, R.string.example6, R.string.example7},
};
CharSequence[][] childview = fromRes(resIds);
```